# Securing the application deployed on GKE through APIGEE proxy

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, apigee

I have a spring boot application deployed on GKE that I have managed to secure with a proxy created in APIGEE x ,but at this point my application can be accessed directly through an external ip that I use as a target url for my apigee proxy as well as with apigee proxy url.

I want to restrict access to that application using APIGEE url only , so in other words no one should be able to hit the external ip url through browser or any other client  (exposed through a load balancer kubernetes service ) and should only be accessing it through my api proxy url.

Can you please suggest what all changes do I need to make to my Kubernetes service that exposes its external ip ?

Comment: what type of security you are trying to apply? i mean what is the need for this "proxy"?

Comment: So, ideally all my requests to my spring boot application url should be made through this apigee proxy , so the only url that I should be able to hit is the apogee proxy url which will in turn call application deployed on gcp but since that url is exposed through load balancer service and has an external ip ,it can be accessed by browser or any other client directly . Can there be any controls so that only requests coming from apogee proxy url are entertained and no other requests are answered by tat service? @AtefHares

Comment: I am not sure if you can use Apigee endpoint to pass requests to internal load balancer! you can try to make your LB internal and test. But if you are just trying to use this proxy to limit who can access your service, you can achieve this through using Cloud Armor and/or configuring IAP for your public LB.

Comment: With Cloud Armor, you can configure which cidr range/s your users can initiate requests from. and with IAP you can control which Identity is authorized to access your service.